# How to match strings between two words but display also the first word

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to match specific string between two words and display also the first word. The string between two words is “First Time : 10:10PM”.

I have regex matching between two words but it displays all between >Z and First Time.

https://regex101.com/r/iVBUCQ/1

Data:

```
qitjfjdjqkfjjf 1934848[*.    {*}*}*#*#*#[#*
]*,qgvv]*?£[£?£,£~'_!~£[££<£<'<'?  £]!<!<
['~£,'}'<',!']'',',    <€~Z1234566789>Z12345667890
1'fncnr'qmtjcsmsj194&($.!:!
,$/&15?'?'(''(('(''158,$3,!!1
1'('(',';?1!( First Time : 10:10PM
1&4$,!;($qmfjccn1'fkfkckcqtngcnnq
AAABBB : ,$2$$(&158((&&,&,&;&(&&((&
```

Desired Result:

```
>Z12345667890 First Time : 10:10PM
```

Comment: You can not get just those 2 parts in 1 match, you need for example 2 capture groups.

Comment: What do you mean by "display"? Are you trying to replace all the text under "Data" with the text under "Desired Result"?

Comment: I want to mark them together in notedpad++ and copy to excel since there are multiple records the pair should be within the strings between >Z1234567890 and AAABBB

Comment: Try this: `\b[AZQ]\d{10,14}>(\S+).*?(First Time : \d\d:\d\d[AP]M).*?\sAAABBB\b`

Comment: @anubhava That should do it! https://regex101.com/r/BQXkZh/1

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with 2 capture groups:

```bash
\b[AZQ]\d{10,14}(>\S+).*?(First Time : \d\d:\d\d[AP]M)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Mto17/2)

- `\b[AZQ]\d{10,14}`: Match word boundary followed by letter `[AZQ]` followed by 10 to 14 digits
- `(>\S+)`: Capture group #1 to match `>` followed by 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `.*?`: Match any text or line break
- `(First Time : \d\d:\d\d[AP]M)`: Capture group #2 to match `First Time :`  followed by hour:minute and `AM` or `PM`
- `.*?`: Match any text or line break
- `\s`: Match a whitespace
- `AAABBB\b`: Match `AAABBB` and word boundary

Comment: Hi @anubhava, really appreciate your response. But I came to realize that AAABBB is not always there, can you modify the pattern? The result should be Z12345667890 1'fncnr'qmtjcsmsj194&($.!:! ,$/&15?'?'(''(('(''158,$3,!!1 1'('(',';?1!( First Time : 10:10PM

Comment: ok please try: `\b[AZQ]\d{10,14}(>\S+).*?(First Time : \d\d:\d\d[AP]M)` as regex